# How do I use C Module Maps in an Xcode Playground?

Tags: xcode, import, swift-playground, module-map

I have an Xcode playground and projects in a workspace, so I can import those projects into the playground.

This setup works until I try to import a project that uses C module maps. The project itself imports, but I get errors such as `error: missing required module 'CNIOAtomics'`.

Is there a way to import C module maps and packages that use module maps in an Xcode playground?